# remove object from the array PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I try to remove pixelId":"AW-23423524124" from the array and in case its the only one in the array trackingIds than remove the entire object of pxg. it does not work using PostgreSQL

```
    UPDATE clicks
SET protection_config =
    CASE
        WHEN protection_config LIKE '%{"pxg":{"trackingIds":[{"pixelId":"AW-23423524124"%' AND jsonb_array_length(replace(replace(protection_config, 'false', '0'), 'true', '1')::jsonb->'pxg'->'trackingIds') = 1
            THEN '{}'
        WHEN protection_config LIKE '%{"pxg":{"trackingIds":[{"pixelId":"AW-23423524124"%' AND jsonb_array_length(replace(replace(protection_config, 'false', '0'), 'true', '1')::jsonb->'pxg'->'trackingIds') > 1
            THEN replace(replace(protection_config, 'false', '0'), 'true', '1')::jsonb #- '{pxg, trackingIds}' || jsonb_build_object('pxg', jsonb_build_object('trackingIds', (replace(replace(protection_config, 'false', '0'), 'true', '1')::jsonb->'pxg'->'trackingIds') #- '{0}' #- '{pixelId}'))::text
        ELSE protection_config
    END
WHERE protection_config LIKE '%{"pxg":{"trackingIds":[{"pixelId":"AW-23423524124"%' and network_id='5766'
```

column looks like that-- please note the column is type -character varying

```
{"monitoringMode":{"isMonitoring":false,"dates":null},"pxg":{"trackingIds":[{"active":1,"pixelId":"AW-23423524124"}]},"uaTrackingIds":[{"pixelId":"UA-123","dimensionIndex":"dimension123"},{"pixelId":"UA-1233","dimensionIndex":"dimension3"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can benefit from converting the column in question to a json type. Kind of

```
update clicks
  set protection_config = (
     select case when array_agg(e) is null then '{}'
            else jsonb_build_object('pxg',jsonb_build_object('trackingIds', to_jsonb(array_agg(e))))::varchar(2000)
            end
     from jsonb_array_elements(protection_config::jsonb ->'pxg' ->'trackingIds') ids(e)      
     where e->>'pixelId' != 'AW-23423524124'
  )
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/C9eOcVPP)

Comment: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "pxg" is invalid.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/7peRXbP6

Comment: The string in  your fiddle is not a correct JSON. Please check your data.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/aSBtkpqJ
Updated

Comment: as you can see everything is removed and not just the pxg object

Comment: Json data structure in your fiddle is different from the one in question. You should ask another question for different data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I used almost same logic as yours.

`json_array_length` to get array length.

`jsonb_path_query_array` used to get data as array based on condition.

`jsonb_set` to update our json.

[Docs here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html)

```
 with cte as (
   select network_id, CASE
   WHEN trackingIdsLength = 1 
       THEN jsonb_set(
             protection_config, '{pxg}','{}', false)
       WHEN trackingIdsLength  > 1
         THEN jsonb_set( 
             protection_config, '{pxg,trackingIds}', 
             jsonb_path_query_array(to_jsonb(protection_config::jsonb->'pxg'->'trackingIds'), '$[*] ? (@.pixelId <> "AW-23423524124")')
         )
    ELSE protection_config END as new_protection_config
  from (
    select network_id, protection_config::jsonb, 
    json_array_length(to_json(protection_config::jsonb->'pxg'->'trackingIds')) as trackingIdsLength
    from clicks c
    cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(protection_config::jsonb->'pxg'->'trackingIds') as e
    where e ->> 'pixelId' like 'AW-23423524124'
  ) as s
)
update clicks c
set protection_config = cte.new_protection_config
from cte
where c.network_id = cte.network_id
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/X7Kq9VhR)

To remove the entire object `pxg` use this instead :

```
set protection_config = REGEXP_REPLACE(new_protection_config::text, '("pxg": {}[,]?)(.*)','\2')
```

Comment: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Expected end of input, but found ",".
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: ...123"},{"pixelId":"123","dimensionIndex":"123"}]},...

Comment: I updated the column data

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/IBg6jHaj

Comment: This json is invalid, check it here : https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/Tc1JKea0
sorry, here is the json valid example

Comment: Can you check my update

Comment: in id 5770 the object AW-23423524124 is not  being removed

Comment: @biillitil `23423524124` is removed and `234824124` not

Comment: @SelVazi you are correct but pxg needs to remove completely since trackingids length is 0. sorry for the confusion

Comment: { "uaTrackingIds": [{"pixelId": "UA-123", "dimensionIndex": "dimension123"}, {"pixelId": "UA-1233", "dimensionIndex": "dimension3"}], "monitoringMode": {"dates": null, "isMonitoring": false}}
the expected result